# Relation between convex and almost convex metric space

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces

I am struggling to prove a claim in a text I have been studying. The problem is that it does not indicate any reference, and I could not find any material discussing both concepts.

A metric space $(X,d)$ is called **convex** if for all $x,y \in X$ there is $z \in X\setminus\{x,y\}$ satisfying
$$d(x,y)=d(x,z)+d(z,y).$$
It is called **almost convex** if for every $x,y \in X$ and $s,t>0$ such that
$$d(x,y)<s+t$$
there exists $z \in X$ satisfying
$$d(x,z)<s \quad \text{and} \quad d(z,y)<t.$$
The claim is that every convex metric space is almost convex. For my purposes, it suffices to prove that every linear normed convex space is almost convex. Still, I can't see how one concept implies the other one. All I can see is that we have a sequence of "intermediate" points by convexity, but how can I guarantee they are at the desired distance?

Also, I would appreciate any reference that discusses both of these concepts.

Comment: Consider $d(x,z) + d(z,s)$. Can you see how that helps?

Answer (score 1):

First that for $\overline{X}$ closure of $X$ we have:

$X$ convex $\rightarrow$ $\overline{X}$ convex

$\overline{X}$ almost convex $\rightarrow$ $X$ almost convex.

So it is enough to prove it for closed linear normed convex spaces.

Also, we note that in normed convex spaces if we have $d(x,z)+d(z,y)=d(x,y)$ then z is on the line between $x$ and $y$. Now we want to proof that all elements on the line between $x,y$ are in $X$.

Now define $D=$ {$r\leq d|\exists z\in X, d(x,z) = r, d(z,y)=d-r$} where $d=d(x,y)$.

And note that since $X$ is closed there an injective map from $D$ to the line between $x$ and $y$ so each element in $D$ is corresponds to a point in that line.

Now it is enough to prove that $D=[0,d]$ or we have all points on the line between $x$ and $y$.

For proof assume we have two numbers $0\leq l<r\leq d$ where for all $l<t<r$ we don't have any $z\in X$ such that $d(x,z)=t$ and $d(z,y)=d-t$, but $l,r\in D$. Since $l,r\in D$ we have $z_l,z_r\in X$ such that:

- $d(x,z_l)=l$
- $d(z_l,y)=d-l$
- $d(x,z_r)=r$
- $d(z_r,y)=d-r$

Now since $z_l,z_r\in X$ we have third point $z\in X$ such that $d(z_l,z)+d(z,z_r)=d(z_l,z_r)$. now since it is on the line between $z_l,z_r$ so is on the line between $x,y$ and then $d(x,z)+d(z,y)=d(x,y)$ but $d(x,z)>l$ and $d(z,y)<r$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a metric space with two points and distant $1$ from each other, then for $s=t=0.5$ there is no third point that satisfies the almost convex condition. So it is not true that any convex metric space is almost convex.

Comment: Well, suppose we need $z$ different from $x$ and $y$. I see that I have not written in such a way but this is the only way the definition makes sense. Now edited.